# How to select (and copy) a single object from a PDF I open with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

The whole PDF appears as one object, even though I can see the outlines of all the sub objects.

I would like to ungroup, or expand this big object, but I am not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to release the clipping mask. Right click on the PDF and select Release Clipping Mask

[image: release clipping mask]

You could also do Isolate Selected Clipping Mask to enter the clipping mask and select the objects that way.

You could even leave the clipping mask as-is and use the Direct Selection Tool (A) and select the objects.

[image: direct selection tool]

The Direct Selection Tool is the white arrow.

Comment: Yes it worked. Double clicking to "enter" the group of objects also worked. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Can you add a picture about "Direct Selection Tool"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the layers palette and start opening up the layer objects (using the little pointers next to each nested layer object) being sure to unlock the layer sub-groups. There may be a whole poop-load of sub layers but it'll be in there somewhere.